# Clicking "Add Event Handler..." on a top menu option in Microsoft Visual Studio doesn't do anything

Tags: visual-studio

I have had this issue on two versions of Microsoft Visual Studio: the Community 2017 version and the Enterprise 2019 version. When I right-click on the menu item I'm trying to add an event for and click "Add Event Handler..." as pictured below, I expect to see a wizard for adding events, but nothing happens.

[image: Screenshot of "Add Event Handler..." right-click menu option]

Does anyone know how I can fix this?

Comment: Can updating or repairing Visual Studio solve your issue?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use Visual Studio Installer to repair or update Visual Studio.

**Update:**

[image]

**Repair:**

[image]